# How to resize joint arrows

Tags: gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there some way to decrease the size of the joint arrows? I'm modelling parts that are less than a cm, and the arrows seem to render about 5 cm in diameter, causing them to blot out my model.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8427/how-to-resize-joint-arrows/) by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, right now the joint visuals have a fixed size.

Please follow [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1563/scale-joint-visuals) to see when this is improved.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1